# Facebook/Swift: Debugger skipping over lines

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to execute a FBSDKGraphRequest in Swift and run some code inside of it. The problem is that in the following code, `"Boston"` is being printed before `"numbersArray: \(numbersArray)")`, which doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't the `graphRequest` function finish executing before anything that follows it? How can I fix this issue?

```
class Test {

    class func test() {

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
            var numbersArray = [String]()

            for number in array {
                numbersArray.append(number)
            }

            println("numbersArray: \(numbersArray)")

        })

        println("Boston")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler you set a closure that will be called asynchronously when the request has done.

Although it would possible to transform in some way that call in a synchronous call, it doesn't make sense because this is the expected behaviour, otherwise the thread, probably the main_thread, would be stuck until the call has done.

Comment: That makes sense. But it begs me to ask another question. I'd appreciate if you took a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470328/fb-swift-how-to-append-an-array-via-a-for-loop-in-fbsdkgraphrequest