# FB/Swift: How to append an array via a for-loop in FBSDKGraphRequest?

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, for-loop

In the following code, I'm having trouble appending values to an array via a `for` loop in an asynchronous call. I'm declaring the `numbersArray` array outside the `graphRequest` so that I can try to append values from inside the `for` loop to it and access it outside the request.  Problem is, because `graphRequest` is an asynchronous call, it prints `"Boston: \(numbersArray)")` before printing `"numbersArray: \(numbersArray")"`.

`"numbersArray: \(numbersArray")"` prints the values of the array after each loop, while `"Boston: \(numbersArray)")` prints an empty array since it was called before the `graphRequest`. How can I access `numbersArray` with it's values **outside** the `graphRequest`?

```
class Test {

    class func test() {

        var numbersArray = [String]()

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

            for number in array {
                numbersArray.append(number)
            }

            println("numbersArray: \(numbersArray)")

        })

        println("Boston: \(numbersArray)")

    }
}
```

---

Update: Here's how I edited the code.

```
class Test {

        class func test() {

            var numbersArray = [String]()

            var arrayDidChange:Bool = false {
                didSet {
                   if arrayDidChange {
                     println("Boston: \(numbersArray)")
                   }
                }
            }

            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/", parameters: nil)
            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

                for number in array {
                    numbersArray.append(number)
                    arrayDidChange = true
                }


            })

            arrayDidChange = false

        }
    }
```

---

Update #2: I can't get the observer to just print once in this code. I've moved the `arrayDidChange`s all around and have had no success. If I move the `arrayDidChange = true` statement out of the `for` loop, then `songArray` is empty.

```
class Test {

    class func test() {

        var songArray = [String]()
        var testArray = ["Trap Queen", "Dream Lover", "All Of Me"]

        var arrayDidChange: Int = 0 {
            didSet {
               if arrayDidChange == 0 {
                   println("Boston: \(songArray)")
               }
            }
        }

        arrayDidChange++

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/music.listens", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if let data = result["data"] as? NSArray {

                for songs in data {

                    if let songData = songs["data"] as? NSDictionary {

                        if let song = songData["song"] as? NSDictionary {

                            if let id = song["id"] as? String {

                                let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\(id)", parameters: nil)
                                graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                                    if let title = result["title"] as? String {

                                        if contains (testArray, title) {

                                            songArray.append(title)

                                            arrayDidChange--
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You added your async block inside of the for loop, that will complicate a bit, you will need to create a counter instead a boolean increase it before you call startWithCompletionHandler and decrease from inside the block. In the didSet you will print when the value is zero. However this way your app will update just in the end what that all the propose of the async call

Comment: Maybe this will make it still async and solve your problem, in println("Boston: \(numbersArray)") change it to println("Boston: \(numbersArray.last)") so it will be printed as before but just the new entry.

Comment: @IcaroNZ Hmm I can't use `numbersArray.last` because I need to retrieve the fully appended array just once. I'm trying your first suggestion, but it's only printing the first value. Am I utilizing your method correctly?

Comment: Using numbersArray.last doesn't mean you will use just the last one, it means for each new row you add you will read the new row, for example if you add 3 rows, it will add the 1 first, print the last that is the first, add the second, print the last that is the second and so on. You can animate new rows been add in a table view as it gets read and have a full table view in the end

Comment: Another way is to implement the count as I explain to you before

Comment: I understand I'm getting all the objects with `numbersArray.last`, which is OK. But my `println("Boston: \(songArray)")` is eventually going to be a save method, which means I'll be saving objects one by one, rather than in one batch. And the count method is a bit confusing, would you mind appending it to my current code?

Comment: There is no problem in save one at the time, in this case is actually better, just save in a background thread, will be faster then download all and save all in a batch trust me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FBSDKGraphRequest is async so it will happen in the background thread while your program still running in the main thread, by the point your background thread comeback with the data the println command was already executed. One of the best solutions for your problem is to add observers for the result so you will be notified when it happens. Add observers to array can be a little bit trick and I want to keep it simple for you, so I would recommend you to create a boolean variable that tells you when the value finish change. To do so you will need to create the variable like this

```
var arrayDidChange:Bool = false {
    didSet{
        if arrayDidChange{
            callFuncDataReadArrayHere()
        }
    } 
}
```

Now everytime you change the values (add or edit) in the array you set arrayDidChange to true and after you read it and do all you need to do you set arrayDidChange to false.

This way you will always be sure you will access the values in the array after it be populate.

I hope that helped you!

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what `callFuncDataReadArrayHere()` means. Would you mind clarifying what to do in that call?

Comment: That call will do whatever you want to do with the array after you have the data, in this specific example you post would just to a println("Boston: \(numbersArray)")

Comment: See updated code above. My question is, `"Boston \(numbersArray)"` is printing three times, once per loop, even though it's out of the `for` loop and `graphRequest`. Any way to get it to just print once, or will it always print `array.count` times?

Comment: You need to add the arrayDidChange = true after you finish add or edit the array, just move it outside your for loop

Comment: It doesn't work in my project, but it does in the code I gave you. So for that, I'll accept your answer! Brilliant!! Just need to figure out why it's not working in my own project now.

Comment: Thanks man, I hope you can make it work in your app now. Good luck!

Comment: Would you be so kind as to take a gander at Update #2 posted above? I've been at this for hours now with no luck.